# React-native: Images not showing in android device; but shows in emulator

Tags: android, react-native

Here is my code :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
     Platform, 
     StyleSheet, 
     Text, 
     View , 
     ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
 export default class App extends Component {
 render() {
 return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}>
    <ImageBackground source={{uri: "image1"}} style={{ width: null , height: null , flex: 1, resizeMode: 'cover',}} 
     >
     </ImageBackground>

</View>
 );
}
}

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
 flex: 1,
 justifyContent: 'center',
 alignItems: 'center',
 backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
 },
 welcome: {
 fontSize: 20,
 textAlign: 'center',
 margin: 10,
  },
 instructions: {
 textAlign: 'center',
 color: '#333333',
 marginBottom: 5,
 },
});
```

And when I try this in emulator everything is Ok but on my device
images not showing

[Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hngr1.png)
[Files tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BHPg.png)

Why this happen ? :(  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting the images inside an assets folder at the root of your project, then you could reference to it using the require method, then path will be relative to the component location.

source={require('../assets/image1.jpg')}

This way you can also put files of different resolutions like this:

- image1.png
- image1@2x.png
- image1@3x.png
- image1@4x.png

Inside that that folder and RN will load accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The uri is pretty important here.  Images displaying in the emulator and not on your device seems like we are dealing with images you uploaded in the app? (As opposed to static images that you include somewhere in your project or network images).  On your emulator, the path to storage is different than on the device, so you'll have to make sure you are using a uri that correctly points to the image based on environment.  Hope that helps!

Comment: I tested it in htc and Hoffmann device ,And again in hoffmann everything is ok :D but in Htc images not displayed . I'll go crazy :/

Answer (score 0):

First go your project path in terminal then run this command

react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

Then run in android device. Hope it works.